# Missing tabs on netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm using Netbeans IDE on daily basis and suddenly my Projects and Files tabs disappeared and I really don't know what to do, I've searched Google and I can't find any suitable and working solution to this problem.
Can someone help me please?
I'm using Netbeans 7.4 on Windows 7 if you need the information.
Thanks!

This is how my Netbeans looks right now, missing Projects and Files tab -

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The solution in this case is really simple.
Since Netbeans 7.1 and up just click on the Window button on the upper bar and select the window you want, ex: Projects.
The window tab - 
[image]

Alternatively you can click on CTRL + (A number from 1 to 7) and a tab with the selected information will be opened.
For example, clicking on CTRL + 1 will open your Projects Tab. Clicking on CTRL + 2 will open the Files Tab.

Enjoy and happy coding!

Comment: checked all the menu and i skip 'window' menu. how could i miss that

Answer (score 3):

Click Window > Reset Windows will give you back the old state of all windows!